# Save the part found in a regex expression php

Tags: php

I'm using this:

```
<?php echo preg_replace("/\[car:\s*(\d+)\]/", "<a href=".base_url("logs/veh/" . MISSING_PART).">[car:".MISSING_PART."]</a>", $row->log); ?>
```

I'm using this to found : [car: car_id] and put a a href link on it. But I need the id of the car found instead of MISSING_PART

For example:
[car: 1]

```
<a href=".base_url("logs/veh/" . 1).">[car: 1]</a>
```

Someone have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a capture group (`1`), you would use it as the replacement (`\1`):

```
preg_replace("/\[car:\s*(\d+)\]/", '<a href="' . '.base_url(\'logs/veh/' . '\1' . '\')">[car:\1]</a>', $row->log);
```

If `098765` was the captured `car_id` you should ultimately end up with a url such as:

```
<a href=".base_url('logs/veh/098765')">[car:098765]</a>
```

If `base_url` is a function (as mentioned in the comments) then you could do:

```
preg_replace("/\[car:\s*(\d+)\]/", '<a href="' . base_url("logs/veh/$1") . '">[car:\1]</a>', $row->log);
```

Which should result in:

```
<a href="logs/veh/098765">[car:098765]</a>
```

Comment: `base_url()` appears to be a PHP function, not a literal string that should be included in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

`$1` in the replacement string will be replaced with the part that matched the first capture group in the regexp.

But if you need to call a function (e.g. `base_url()`) to get the replacement string, you have to use `preg_replace_callback()`. The argument to the function is an array whose element `0` is the whole match, and other elements are the captured groups.

```
<?php echo preg_replace("/\[car:\s*(\d+)\]/", 
                function($matches) {
                    return "<a href=".base_url("logs/veh/" . $matches[1]).">[car:".$matches[1]."]</a>";
                }, $row->log); ?>
```